# Not instant Remote Config value android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'

FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
            .setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .build();

    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(configSettings);

    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(0).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                String appDefaultColor = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString(FIREBASE_REMOTE_CONFIG_DEFAULT_COLOR);
                if (appDefaultColor != null && appDefaultColor.length() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("==== appDefaultColor : " + appDefaultColor);
                }
            }

        }
    });

public static String FIREBASE_REMOTE_CONFIG_DEFAULT_COLOR = "project_default_theme_color";
```

here is my implementation of Firebase remote config.
As above my code explanation, **project4_default_theme_color**, i get the value from firebase, But the situation is that i change that value from Firebase remote config , but i did't get.

My firebase remote config Key **project_default_theme_color** and value is **#f04030** and Publish Changes.is any wrong in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow below instruction to resolve this issue**

- Update your firebase library version

  ```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
  ```
- Initialize FirebaseRemoteConfig

  ```
  FirebaseRemoteConfig firebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
  ```
- Set firebaseRemoteConfig parameter default value

  ```
  firebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(R.xml.remote_config_defaults);
  ```
- Add below code in remote_config_defaults.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <defaultsMap>
      <entry>
          <key>your_key</key>
          <value>defaultValue</value>
  </entry>
  ```
- Add this code in your java file

  ```
     firebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheTimeDuration)
          .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                  String errorString = "";

                  if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                      firebaseRemoteConfig.activate();
                      errorString = " task is successful  ";
                  } else {
                      errorString = "task is canceled";
                  }
                  Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: error " + errorString);
                  Log.i(TAG, " Get firebase remote config value " + firebaseRemoteConfig.getString("your_key"));

              }
          });
  ```
- **Note :**

  - If your Apk is debug then use this method `.fetch(cacheTimeDuration)`
  - If your Apk is Release then use this method `.fetch()`